# Beanstalk - eb branch command not found

Tags: amazon-web-services, git, aws-cli, amazon-beanstalk

I'm new to AWS and I'm trying to get a Node.js app running using Beanstalk.
The app is running now and I would like to deploy code from a prod git branch.

I followed this tutorial: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/command-reference-branch-environment.html

But when I try to run:

```
eb branch
```

I get

```
$ eb branch
usage: eb (sub-commands ...) [options ...] {arguments ...}
eb: error: unrecognized arguments: branch
```

I installed EB CLI 3.10.0 (Python 3.6.0) and I'm on maxOS Sierra (10.12.3).

Why is this command not working?

Thanks!
nicondev

Comment: Are you sure that the `eb` command in your PATH is the version 3.10 that you installed? What does `eb --version` show?

Comment: Yes: 
$ eb --version
EB CLI 3.10.0 (Python 3.6.0)

Comment: Is your working directory a git repository? Did you run `eb init` in step 4?

Comment: Yes, both. It's a git repo, currently on a branch called production and I ran eb init before

Comment: did you get to tix this issue? i am having the same problem

Comment: it was removed in version 3. "The most significant change from 2.6 is that EB CLI no longer natively supports incremental code updates (eb push, git aws.push) or branching (eb branch)."